# Prove Independence of a Bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, bivariate-distributions

Two variables $X,Y$ are bivariate normally distributed. We know that $Var(X)=Var(Y)$. Show that the two random variables $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent.

I'm feeling pretty stumped by this question, and I hope you guys can help me out.

My foremost instinct is to somehow prove that $\rho=0$, but I have a lot of doubts and questions toward that aim, for which I can't seem to find answers in my text. Can I assume that $X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2)$? Should I try to integrate the joint PDF of X and Y to find E(XY)?

I think I should set up the transformations:
$U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$
but beyond that, I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
cov(X+Y, X-Y) &=  Var(X)-Var(Y)+Cov(X,Y)-Cov(X,Y)\\
&= 0 
\end{align}

Hence, they are uncorrelated.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Did you use the formula $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-\mu_X\mu_Y$? How did you arrive at that equation?

Comment: see the [covariance of linear combination part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

Comment: @skwirlyburd This simply uses the bilinearity of covariance:  In general $Cov(aX+bY, cZ+dW) =  ac\,Cov(X,Z)+ad\,Cov(X,W)+bc\,Cov(Y,Z)+bd\,Cov(Y,W)$ and $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$, and in this particular case $a=b=c=1, d=-1, Z=X, W=Y$